# sql update column value using result in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table T1

```
Fruit | Quantity
----------------
Apple | 2
Grape | 3
```

I have table T2

```
Factor
------
  2
```

I want final result

```
Fruit | Quantity
----------------
Apple | 4
Grape | 6
```

A little confused how to do an update since my second table doesn't have any id's I can join on.
I am using RedShift.

Comment: Will `T2` ever have any additional values?  If so, how do you intend to handle that situation?

Comment: nope. just one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.fruit, t1.quantity * t2.factor
from t1
cross join t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE T1
SET Quantity = Quantity * T2.factor
FROM T2

-- optional
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
```

see working [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dbda4/1)